Langchain Onenote Loader Authentication Not Working?
I'm hoping to work with OneNote using langchain but run into issue at authentication. I followed the instruction (https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/microsoft_onenote/)
However, I tried two approaches mentioned in the post but both end up failing.
Approach 1:

    from langchain_community.document_loaders.onenote import OneNoteLoader
    
    os.environ['MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID'] = "xxxx"
    os.environ['MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET'] = "xxxx"
    
    loader = OneNoteLoader()
    documents = loader.load()


The link to the consent page will appear, as described in the article. The "resulting page url" is "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=M.C501_BAY.2.U.733bb907-eba8-8e2f-227e-67f8f1b7933c&lc=1033" for me, and the page content is blank. Posting that because I don't know what it should be/look like. After pasting to console, I'll get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\test_onenote_1\lc_onenote_2.py", line 16, in <module>
    documents = loader.load()
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\document_loaders\base.py", line 29, in load
    return list(self.lazy_load())
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\onenote.py", line 65, in lazy_load
    self._auth()
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\document_loaders\onenote.py", line 164, in _auth
    self.access_token = access_token_json["access_token"]
KeyError: 'access_token'

Approach 2 - auth with token

    from langchain_community.document_loaders.onenote import OneNoteLoader
    
    os.environ['MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID'] = "xxxx"
    os.environ['MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET'] = "xxxx"
    
    loader = OneNoteLoader(auth_with_token=True)
    documents = loader.load()


And I'll get a 400 Response in def lazy_load in langchain_community\document_loaders\onenote.py\that
'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2024-04-30T20:19:21","request-id":"a46a32a8-0982-4439-af57-c75e4bac2c88","client-request-id":"a46a32a8-0982-4439-af57-c75e4bac2c88"}}}'

Any suggestion is appreciated!
